# System.Reflection.TargetInvocation Exception in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I am getting the following error in my code

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: An exception occurred
>   during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException
>   for exception details.

The error occur on the following line:

```
var rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(e.Result);
```

any help?
Below is my complete code

```
 using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
using Java.Lang;

namespace App3
{
    [Activity(Label = "App3", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.list_view);
            populateList();
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            // SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        }

        public void populateList()
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += C_DownloadStringCompleted;
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new System.Uri("http://10.0.2.2:52485/api/register"));

        }

        private void C_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(e.Result);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.PrintStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public class UserInfo
    {
        public int userId { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Check InnerException for exception details."   Did you do that?

Comment: The `DeserializeObject` method is most likely failing internally. There's many reasons why it might fail when Reflecting. You should check the `InnerException` and potentially the `Message` of the `Exception` being thrown.

Comment: how to check inner exception? @jason

Comment: @Naila you can print the `ex.InnerException`

Comment: @Prashant it's not even going in the catch block. I have tried debuging but it breaks at the line mentioned.

Comment: I have checked the issue by e.Error in try block. It's giving 404 error. i.e System.net.webException. @Prashant

Comment: that means you have a networking problem - it can't even find your webservice

Comment: thanks @Jason. It was a server error. Solved it in webApi